# Excepcion no controlada

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

tengo la siguiente tabla en sql server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

desde  c# tengo un formulario que puede editar estos campos pero me sale la siguiente excepción pero tengo otras tablas con el mismo codigo y la misma estructura y no sale solo sale con esta por que pasa esto

**System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Por que pasa esto ¿?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si pasas el mouse por sobre el `Value` de la celda, que valor observas? quizas no sea una fecha valida o quizas la celda este vacia o null, lo cual no podra convertir

Comment: Obtiene o establece el valor de la fecha y ahora asignado al control

Comment: Pero lo que no entiendo e porque pasa solo con este si los otros están igual

Comment: Coloca código para reproducir tu escenario, las imágenes ayudan para ver errores. El código en formato texto genera más facilidad para quienes desean ayudarte :D

Comment: @Hackerman imprime dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value no es una cadena adecuada para ser convertida a DateTime.

Comment: es el valor de tu entrada no puede realizar la conversion, agrega la declaracion de esa variable y que valor tiene al momento de fallar

Comment: No logro entender todo lo estoy enviando con el tipo de dato e revisado mas de  10 veces y no logro ver que es

Comment: @Hackerman agregue respuesta, te sugiero agregar tu código como texto en lugar de imagen, es importante para el sitio y para que los desarrolladores te apoyen de una forma más rápida y adecuada, saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si analizas el error:

> String was not reconized as a valid DateTime (La cadena no fue
>   reconocida como un DateTime válido)

El valor que se obtiene de `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value` no tiene un formato adecuado que pueda convertirse a `DateTime` mediante `Convert.ToDateTime(...)`

La cadena que estas tratando de convertir es "6/19/2019 3:40:00 PM" que tendría un formato:

```
M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss
```

En lugar de  `Convert.ToDateTime(...)` , Te sugiero usar  `DateTime.ParseExact(...)` de esta forma:

```
  frm.dateFin.Value =  DateTime.ParseExact(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value, new string[] { "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Es importante comentar que se deben definir los formatos:

`M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt` y `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` ,ya que en ocasiones puedes tener 2 digitos en el mes y dos digitos en la hora